# ConstraintLayout is gone when the width is set to "match_constraint"

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am making `CardView` with three `ConstraintLayouts`.  One `ConstraintLayout` wraps two `ConstraintLayout` which are located side by side.
The problem is that right-sided `ConstraintLayout` is gone if the width is set to `match_constraint`. It seems fine in `Android Studio`, but it is gone when I run this on my phone. I assume that the reason "match_constraint" sets the width to 0dp. I want the right-sided Constraint to dynamically change the width depending on the phone.
The below is my layout XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_result_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#eee"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/cl_left-panel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@color/blank_color"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_result_quiz_detail"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="115dp"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/iv_result_quiz_detail"
                    card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    card_view:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_no_of_likes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/iv_result_quiz_detail"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/chb_like"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:text="@string/tv_no_of_likes"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    card_view:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/chb_like"
                    card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_result_quiz_detail" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chb_like"
                    android:layout_width="17dp"
                    android:layout_height="17dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/iv_result_quiz_detail"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_like"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/ib_like"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/iv_result_quiz_detail"
                    card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_result_quiz_detail" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/cl_right_panel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:background="@color/blank_color"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cl_left-panel"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cl_left-panel"
                card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cl_left-panel">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_quiz_desc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:text="@string/test_question"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_choice_01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_quiz_desc"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_round_button_mint"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="@string/test_choice"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_quiz_desc"
                    card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_quiz_desc" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_choice_02"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_choice_01"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="@string/test_choice"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_quiz_desc"
                    card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_choice_01" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_choice_03"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_choice_02"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="@string/test_choice"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_quiz_desc"
                    card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_choice_02" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_choice_04"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_choice_03"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="@string/test_choice"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_quiz_desc"
                    card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_choice_03" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I expected is like 
[image: this]

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of design you want to achieve.

Comment: In fact you do not need 3 `ConstraintLayouts` at all. You just need a `LinearLayout` (either vertical or horizontal) that comprises of two `ConstraintLayout`s. Keep in mind, that `ConstraintLayout` is not free, thus standard layouts most possibly are better choice when having light view hierarchy.

Comment: @RachitMishra I added the link of the image which I expected. Thanks.

Comment: @azizbekian Thanks for comment. I thought that I need three because side by side ConstraintLayout need to be included in wrapper to make  the two layouts change the width. Please let me know if there is another way for making side by side change the width without ConstraintLayout wrapper. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! is this resolved?

Comment: @RachitMishra Nope. Not yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your first `ConstraintLayout` (that has fixed width) occupies the entire screen.
Try using `layout_constraintHorizontal_weight` to determine the portion of the screen that each layout occupies.

Left layout:

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_left-panel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/blank_color"
        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/cl_right_panel"
        card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

Right layout:

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_right_panel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@color/blank_color"
        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cl_left-panel"
        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1.5"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cl_left-panel"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cl_left-panel">
```

Note: You don't need the root `LinearLayout`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But, it doesn't work. By the way I remove the root 'LinearLayout'. Thanks a lot.